# Define XML Elements with identical names

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm facing a problem with xml using jaxb.
I'd like to be able to generate such a xml file:

```
<Animals>
<Animal type="A">
    <name>aaaa</name>
    <j>text1</j>
 </Animal>
 <Animal type="A">
    <name>bbbb</name>
    <j>text3</j>
 </Animal>
 <Animal type="A">
    <name>cccc</name>
    <j>text5</j>
 </Animal>
<Animal type="B">
    <name>vvvvv</name>
    <i>3</i>
</Animal>
<Animal type="B">
    <name>ffff</name>
    <i>4</i>
</Animal>
<Animal type="B">
    <name>zzzz</name>
    <i>7</i>
</Animal>
```

The two types have some similar elements and others that are particular. For example, j is required and should not be null if type="A", and i is required and should not be null if type="B". Is this possible?

Here is Animals class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Animals")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
 public class Animals {
@XmlElement(name="Animal")
private List<AnimalA> listA;
@XmlElement(name="Animal")
private List<AnimalB> listB;
//Getters and Setters
...
//Constructors
...
```

}
to test it, here is a main function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Starting here...");
    AnimalA a = new AnimalA("animalA", "valueA");
    AnimalB b = new AnimalB("animalB", "valueb",3);
    AnimalB b2 = new AnimalB("animalB2", "valueb2",56);
    List<AnimalA> listA = new ArrayList<AnimalA>();
    List<AnimalB> listB = new ArrayList<AnimalB>();
    listA.add(a);
    listB.add(b);
    listB.add(b2);
    Animals animals = new Animals(listA,listB);

    JAXBContext context = null;

    try {
        context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Animals.class);

        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        if (animals != null) {
            m.marshal(animals, new File("C:\\animalz.xml"));
        }
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    Animals aa = null;
    URL url = null;
        try {

            url = new File("C:\\animalz.xml").toURI().toURL();
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
            aa  = (Animals) unmarshaller.unmarshal(url);
            int countA = aa.getListA().size();
                   //               int countB = aa.getListB().size();
            System.out.println("size A==>"+countA);
                   //               System.out.println("size B ==>"+countB);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());;
        }
}
```

this returns:
Starting here...
size A==>3
if i uncomment line of CountB, it gets a NullPointerexception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

You could use MOXy's `@XmlPath` extension of this use case:

**Animals**

```java
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;    
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement(name="Animals")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Animals {


    @XmlPath("Animal[@type='A']")
    private List<AnimalA> listA;

    @XmlPath("Animal[@type='B']")
    private List<AnimalB> listB;

}
```

**Demo**

The standard JAXB runtime APIs are used to convert the XML to/from objects.

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Animals.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("input.xml");
        Animals animals = (Animals) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(animals, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Animals>
   <Animal type="A">
      <name>aaaa</name>
      <j>text1</j>
   </Animal>
   <Animal type="A">
      <name>bbbb</name>
      <j>text3</j>
   </Animal>
   <Animal type="A">
      <name>cccc</name>
      <j>text5</j>
   </Animal>
   <Animal type="B">
      <name>vvvvv</name>
      <i>3</i>
   </Animal>
   <Animal type="B">
      <name>ffff</name>
      <i>4</i>
   </Animal>
   <Animal type="B">
      <name>zzzz</name>
      <i>7</i>
   </Animal>
</Animals>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Comment: Yes it works thanks, but without @XmlElement(name = "Animal"), which means that the tags used in xml file are listA and listB. How can i rename them?

Comment: @callafa - To get the `@XmlPath` annotation to work you need to use MOXy as your JAXB provider.  Here is a link to a runnable example:  https://github.com/bdoughan/blog20110322

Comment: @callafa - If you run this code with MOXy as your JAXB provider the element names for `listA` and `listB` will both be `Animal`.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you are looking for is something like:

```
public class Animal {
    @XmlAttribute("type")
    private String type;

    @XmlElement(name="j", required=false)
    private String j;

    @XmlElement(name="i", required=false)
    private String i;
```

I'm not aware of any way for you to enforce that type A *always* has a j element.  If you require that degree of validation, I think you will need a more annoying structure:

```
<Animal_A>
    <j>asdf</j>
</Animal_A>
<Animal_B>
    <i>asdf</i>
</Animal_B>
```